# Can iactorref.tell be called outside from actor from multithread

Tags: c#, akka.net

can IactorRef.tell in akka.net called by multithread?
of course the message passed into tell method will be immutable

is ActorRef.Tell thread safe anyway?

example：（is the following code right?）

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Props props = Props.Create<PrintMyActorRefActor>();
            var sys = ActorSystem.Create("Sys");
            var actorRef = sys.ActorOf(props, "worker");

            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            {
//the message passed into tell method will be immutable
                int j = i;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    actorRef.Tell("printit" + j, ActorRefs.NoSender);
                });
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }


    public class PrintMyActorRefActor : UntypedActor
    {
        protected override void OnReceive(object message)
        {
            string msgStr = message == null ? "" : message.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(msgStr);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `Tell` message is thread safe and maintains order in between two actors - so actor **A** `Tell`ing some messages to actor **B** can count on them being delivered in order they were send - but not across multiple actors.

Messages must be immutable or at least you as an user must guarantee that mutable components of the message are not being accessed from elsewhere (therefore once send, the recipient actor is an owner of that data).

Another thing specific for your code is that you don't need to wrap `actor.Tell` with `Task`: [asynchronous message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Fundamental_concepts) is one of the fundamental concepts of actors, so sending a message doesn't block executing thread.

Comment: "Another thing specific for your code is that you don't need to wrap actor.Tell with Task": I think the multi-threaded example should just help clarify the question. Is it safe to use the same ActorRef instance simultaneously from different threads for telling messages? Kind of a small simulation.

Comment: Yes, ActorRef is thread safe and you can send messages to it from any number of threads (or machines in remote scenarios). These messages are internally queued, and processed by actor one by one. Keep in mind that order of messages is only guaranteed in the scope of the same sender thread.